# Mold from cheese on sausage, is it safe to eat?

Tags: food-safety, cheese, sausages, mold, salami

I stored some sausage together with some blue cheese. There's mold (I assume from the cheese) on the sausage casing. It starts to look like salami (except with less mold). Is it still safe to eat?

The sausage is a [käsekrainer](http://www.visitingvienna.com/eatingdrinking/food/kasekrainer/), it was stored together with roquefort cheese in the fridge, for about 5 days.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! Can you give us more information? What kind of sausage? How was it stored? For how long?

Comment: I have edited the post.

Comment: There are dozens of mold varieties could you please post a picture. However, as the following is just a stab in the dark, I am not going to write it as an answer. Assuming the mold is almost like white fuzz, I would say pick that off and eat the rest of the food as is, it shouldn't hurt you.

Comment: Based on the other answer I threw it out, I should have taken a picture. Sorry.

Comment: This is the perfect cross-contamination lesson. Don't store dissimilar things together. Fridge 101.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it was normal blue cheese, there's a pretty high chance the mold is *Penicillium roqueforti*, which is harmless. However, if the mold comes from something else, it can be basically whatever. In order to assess what kind of mold it is, you need to evaluate if it could have gone from the cheese to the sausage.

What kind of sausage is it? Was it [saucisson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saucisson) or a dry sausage, or a [chipolata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chipolata), or [wurst](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sausage), or something different? Do you mean that it looked like salami before the mold grew on it, or that now that it's there it looks like salami? Was it already cooked? Were they stored in the fridge or at room temperature, and for how long?

If it's a dry sausage or already cooked, it's pretty unlikely that a foreign mold would appear on it, so you could conclude that it's the mold from the cheese, therefore safe. However, if it was a pretty "wet" sausage that you stored at room temp, I wouldn't suggest eating it.

Comment: The sausage is a käsekrainer, a type of Viennese wurst, it was stored together with Roquefort cheese in the fridge, for about 5 days. It looked like a regular sausage when I put it in the fridge, but now a white film is growing on it. It's much thinner than the mold of a real salami.

Comment: Ah, five days is quite a lot. Besides, a spot of dark blue mold would have been a giveaway of Roquefort mold, but a white film does not look good (it could be a bacterial contamination, unrelated to the cheese, who knows). I would recommend throwing it away just in case. Remember the rule: if you can see the mold or bacteria on more than a tiny spot, then the entire thing is probably contaminated.